# Why does the date in October get miscalculated, date fns

Tags: javascript, angular, date-fns

I'm using the date-fns library and I have a logic that calculates the time from a given date depending on the number I specify.

For example:

number: 1 month

start date: 01/09/2020

end time: (is calculated automatically according to the code below)

```
const startDate = new Date("the date that gets 01/09/2020 in this case")
endTime= add(sub(startDate, {seconds: 1}), {months: numberOfPeriods}).toUTCString();
```

In all months it looks ok, but I have a problem with October, because it gets like an extra 2 hour and then it doesn't calculate it right.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am sending ss from consol which shows calculated endTime

[image]

Comment: Daylight savings time is probably the reason October is hit. You'll probably have a similar bug in spring. I'd suggest how to do it with the `Date` object, but it's not clear to me what this code is supposed to do. (I don't use `date-fns`.)

Comment: ever heard of daylight savings time? That is probably the issue.

Comment: "Spring" time, there is no such problem. 
I don't really have an idea how to fix this error 

And how would you solve this on a Date object? @T.J.Crowder